# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'cat_id' cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this error while up entering data to my table

```
class EntryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */


    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function entry(Request $request){

        $category = category::create(['cat_name' => $request->input('cat_name')]);

         $product= product::create([
            'Product_name'=>$request->input('Product_name'),
            'Produc_quantity'=>$request->input('Produc_quantity'),
            'Product_Desc' =>$request->input('Product_Desc'), 
            'cat_id'=>$category->cat_id]);


class category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('cat_description','cat_name');


    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(product::class);


    }
//
}
```

these are my models

```
class product extends Model
{
    protected   $fillable = array('Product_name','Product_Desc',
                                  'Produc_quantity','sale_price',
                                  'cost_price');
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(category::class);


    }
        //
}
```

[image: this is product table]

[image: this is category table]

I've removed the cat_id from $fillables in product model and this is giving this error and I'm not understanding this I've check many forums and questions but I didn't find an answer
this is product table

```
 Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('product_id');
        $table->string('Product_name');
        $table->string('Product_Desc');
        $table->integer('sale_price');
        $table->integer('cost_price');
        $table->integer('Produc_quantity');
       $table->integer('cat_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('cat_id')->references('cat_id')->on('categories');
        $table->timestamps();
```

this is category table

```
  Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('cat_id');
        $table->string('cat_name');
        $table->string('cat_description');


        $table->timestamps();
```

Comment: It might be a typo but your first class is not erminate `}` before you start your second class

Comment: Is `cat_id` an auto-increment field in your database?

Comment: yes it is auto increment

Comment: Take the cat_id off on your $fillable since it's auto-increment.

Comment: I remove cat_id from $fillables now I'm getting this **SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:**

Comment: Are you sure that it's auto-increment? Can you show the structure of your table?

Comment: I added my migrations pic above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the category has been created successfully?
If so, maybe you need to add `cat_id` to your `$fillable`.
Also when using custom id like `cat_id` you need to add

```
public $primaryKey = 'yourkey'
```

Comment: yes cat_id has been created, do you mean that I have to write like this  `return $this->belongsTo(category::class,'cat_id','cat_id')`

Comment: yes, if you have id in product that named cat_id, you should put it in local key.. if it is just `id` .. then just put the foreign_key as `cat_key`

Comment: yes I have `cat_id` in `products` but it is also not working

Comment: i mean the primary key for product, if it named anything but id, you need to replace `local_key` with the name you gave for your id, can you provide me the migrations for the two models ?

Comment: `Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('cat_id');
            $table->string('cat_name');
            $table->string('cat_description');
            
                  
            $table->timestamps();`

Comment: ` Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('product_id');
            $table->string('Product_name');
            $table->string('Product_Desc');
            $table->integer('sale_price');
            $table->integer('cost_price');
            $table->integer('Produc_quantity');
           $table->integer('cat_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('cat_id')->references('cat_id')->on('categories');
            $table->timestamps(); `

Comment: also added above in the post

Comment: So in the `class product `

you will add this `return $this->belongsTo(category::class, 'cat_id','product_id');`

and in `product class`


you will add this `return $this->belongsTo(product::class, 'product_id','cat_id');`


maybe you need to switch between product_id and cat_id, try it and tell me if it worked

Comment: oky, just remove the local_key and foreign_key, and put in two models this value  : `public $primaryKey =  'yourkey'`

Comment: Thank you it help in solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem actually there is a problem in my `product` model `$fillables` I add `cat_id` in my category model `$fillables` which solve this problem thank you for your help